# formula to delete contents of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

Is there a formula that can be constructed such that, when executed, can delete the contents of another cell?  I'm pretty sure the only way to do this is with VBA/macros, but just wanted to check.

Comment: No, there is not.  You could use Conditional Formatting to effectively "blank"  (make invisible by formatting contents the same color as background) the contents of a different cell, but you can't delete the contents of the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the built-in Excel functions will delete the contents of a cell. But you do have a few options to simulate this effect:

1. Use the `IF` function in the cell you want to "delete" to test for the condition that, if true, should delete its content. Return `""` if the condition is true. Example:

   ```
   =IF(A1="Delete","","Proceed as normal")
   ```
2. Use Conditional Formatting to apply a format that renders the cell's content invisible when a qualifying condition is met.

Comment: Thanks!  The cell who's contents I'd like to delete is a user-input cell (users will be entering numbers there).  So I can't put a formula in that cell unfortunately.  Looks like VBA is the only route.